# same permalink for parent category and child category

Tags: categories, permalinks

i have one category, that category is child of **blog category** and the permalink of this category is:

```
name.com/blog/wordpress-plugins
```

know i want to make a new category with the permalink below:

```
name.com/wordpress-plugins
```

But i cant use **wordpress-plugins** for the permalink of new category. WordPress automatically add **-2** to the new category and make the permalink like:

```
name.com/wordpress-plugins-2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you have created wordpress-plugins twice. Please check your database if it already exists.

Comment: Yes i have a category with wordpress-plugins permalink but this category is child of blog category. Now i want to have a category with wordpress-plugins permalink and with out parent blog category.